# Time and date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
create table app 
(
     start_date date, 
     end_date date, 
     start_time time(7), 
     end_time time(7)
);
```

Input: `5/2/2016 08:00:00 to 12:30:00`

I need to insert rows in to the above table through a stored procedure like

For every one hour between 08:00 and 12:30

```
insert into app values ('5/2/2016', '5/2/2016', '08:00:00', '09:00:00')
insert into app values ('5/2/2016', '5/2/2016', '09:00:00', '10:00:00')
insert into app values ('5/2/2016', '5/2/2016', '10:00:00', '11:00:00')
insert into app values ('5/2/2016', '5/2/2016', '11:00:00', '12:00:00')
```

My code is

```
@j time(7);
@time time(7);

select @time = time from someTable;

SET @j = @startTime;

while (@j <= @endTime)
begin
    INSERT INTO appointmentt(start_date, end_date, start_time, end_time)
    VALUES (@startDate, @startDate, @j, @j + @time, @tutorId);

    SET @j = @j + @time;
end;
```

Getting an error like:

> Operand data type time is invalid for add operator

Comment: Just use `datetime2`. Splitting the time out from the date is an anti-pattern. The `time` type should only be used for time-of-day values where the date doesn't matter, like say the time of a daily scheduled process.

Comment: Also: your `INSERT INTO` statement lists **four** column to insert values into - yet you provide **FIVE** values in the `VALUES()` clause.....

Answer (score 0):

In this case, to add time to a datetime you can cast it first like [this example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/10/30/sql-server-adding-datetime-and-time-values-using-variables/):

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME, @time time
SET @date='2010-10-01'
SET @time='15:00:00'
SET @date=@date+CAST(@time AS DATETIME)
SELECT @date AS DATETIME
```

To add integers to datetimes, you need to use the [dateadd() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms186819.aspx).

For example:

```
DATEADD(second,1,@j)
```

Comment: dateadd() function returns datetime type. Is there any function to get date and time individually ?? @Gaspa79

Comment: @Narendra dateadd() returns the same data type of the date argument passed in, unless it is a string literal in which case it will be datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SET @j=@j+@time;
```

To

```
select  @j = DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(MINUTE, @time), 
                     DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, @time), @j))
```